# Azure Websites Canonical HostName Rule - Loop Redirect

Tags: iis, redirect, azure, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 custom domains set up on Azure Websites:
**mydomain.lt** and **www.mydomain.lt**

DNS registrar's settings:

Subdomain and redirect:

**awverif** -> CNAME: **awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net**
**www**  -> CNAME: **mydomain.azurewebsites.net**

Other redirects:
IP: **137.x.x.x** (IP address provided by Azure) and MX: 79.x.x.x

I can reach my website via mydomain.lt and www.mydomain.lt

What I am trying to do now is to set my Canonical URL in a way, that users coming from 
**www.mydomain.lt** would be automatically redirected to **mydomain.lt** and all relative URL paths returned in a lower case.

I added settings bellow to system.WebServer on Web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <!-- SEO | Section 1 | Whitelist -->
    <rule name="Whitelist - Resources" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?:css/|scripts/|bundles/|images/|install/|config/|umbraco/|umbraco_client/|base/|webresource\.axd|scriptresource\.axd|__browserLink|[^/]*/arterySignalR/.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- SEO | Section 2 | Rewrites (chaining) -->
    <rule name="SEO - Lower case" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{ToLower:{R:1}}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- SEO | Section 3 | Redirecting -->
    <rule name="SEO - HTTP canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(_*)(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="80" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="SEO - Non-canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(_+)(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The resulting behaviour is a redirect loop. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with Azure Websites. The link below gives a workaround how to fix the problem temporarily.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ee3a5f97-8a58-4b42-a2d9-a73cd5d12c01/issues-with-redirect-rules-used-in-url-rewrite-feature?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

I've rewritten my rules and everything works just fine:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Whitelist - Resources" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?:css/|scripts/|bundles/|content/|images/|install/|config/|umbraco/|umbraco_client/|base/|webresource\.axd|scriptresource\.axd|__browserLink|[^/]*/arterySignalR/.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Canonical Host Name" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REMOTE_PORT}" pattern="*" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.lt" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain.lt/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by simplifying your rewrite rules to narrow down the problem:

- Instead of using rewrite for www, just update the CNAME for www.domain.com to point to domain.com
- remove section 3 till you get section 2 working
- then try updating section 2 to:

> ```
> <!-- SEO | Section 2 | Rewrites (chaining) -->
> <rule name="SEO - Lower case" stopProcessing="false">
>   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
>   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
>     <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
>     <add input="{R:1}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
>   </conditions>
>   <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}}" RedirectType="Permanent"/>
> </rule>
> ```

Comment: And what about urls other than root? Let's say I hit www.mydomain.lt/contacts, the redirection would be made to mydomain.lt instead of mydomain.lt/contacts :)

Comment: The point is to forward www - so that there are no URLs at www.  Setup a sitemap and everything will get indexed properly. If you really need a redirect (already indexed at www.) then specify a 301 - Permanent Redirect in your rule.

Comment: And this is where I need some help :) The thing is that when I add rule managing permanent redirects from www to non-www, even when using the rule one itself, url rewritting is resulting a redirect loop. Do you know the reason of this behaviour and how to make this rule to start working correctly?

Comment: read my instructions above. narrow down to one rule and make sure it works.  then add another.  Also - I wouldn't use IIS Rewrite to forward www CNAME - do that at DNS level.